# Is there a projection functor $\mathbf{Set}/X^2 \to \mathbf{Set}/X$

Tags: category-theory, computer-science, type-theory

I have an object in the slice / arrow category $\mathbf{Set}/X^2$ and I want to transport it to $\mathbf{Set}/X$ by forgetting the second element of the index. Reading up on slice categories I've only always encountered the induced base change/substitution functor, but that's not what I am doing here.

I am trying to define a head-indexed List shape/base functor, so for element type $A$, I'm slicing over $A + 1$, and the reason I need this inclusion is because I have:
$L(X \to^{f} (A+1)):= (1\to^{\pi_1} (1+A)) + \text{Mystery functor here }(A\to^{\pi_2} (1+A))\times (X \to^{f} (A+1))$ (where $\times$ is the product in $\mathbf{Set}^{\to}$, so the arrow category.)

What would be the "right" categorical way to go about this?

Comment: Just to confirm, by $\mathbf{Set}/X^2$, you mean $\mathbf{Set}/(X\times X)$ yes? And not the product category $\mathbf{Set}/X \times \mathbf{Set}/X$?

Comment: @Charlie yes I do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is such a functor. In general, let $\mathscr{C}$ be a category, $A$ and $B$ be two objects in that category. For any morphism $f\colon A\to B$ in $\mathscr{C}$, $f$ induces a functor on the slice categories $f_*\colon\mathscr{C}/A\to\mathscr{C}/B$ by sending any $g\colon L\to A$ (as an object in $\mathscr{C}/A$) to $f\circ g\colon L\to B$, which is an object in $\mathscr{C}/B$. I will let you work out how this functor acts on morphisms, and that the compatibility conditions for this to actually be a functor do hold. (Hint: the morphism obtained via pushforward will be described by the same actual function of sets; you just need to check that the new diagram commutes, which will be straightforward.)

In your case, you have the slice category over $X^2=X\times X$ (where $X^2$ is your "$A$" in the above) and the slice category over $X$ (which is your "$B$" in the above). Let $\pi_1\colon X\times X\to X$ be the function which sends a pair $(x_1,x_2)$ to the first coordinate $x_1$ (this is your "$f$"). Then $\pi_1$ induces a functor on your slice categories, which behaves as you would like.

Comment: Can you point me to a source that mentions this construction? And is "pushforward" the standard name for it?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221293/how-does-slice-category-help-create-functor) for a discussion where OP references their use of Awodey's text, which admittedly breezes over this construction. This is the kind of thing which is quite commonly left as an exercise. As for the terminology "pushforward" this is the general term for a functor which arises from (post-)composition. (Similarly, "pullback" is the term for pre-composition.)

Comment: Is this (–)_* functor then right adjoint to the (–)^* functor? I'm trying to figure out if it corresponds to the dependent sum or product. But maybe this goes beyond the scope of the question

Comment: @cxandru this is a generalization of dependent sum, left adjoint to pullback. Dependent product is much rarer in general though it certainly exists for slices of Set.